# Connecting Android Application to MySQL Database hosted on AWS

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Good day everyone,

I have developed an android application and I would like to store my business information on MySQL database. I have decided to use amazon services for this project however I'm very confused how to allow my application to establish a proper/secure connection with MySQL database in order to pull and push the information into it. I have read many articles/stack overflow posts and realized I have to deploy a REST api in order to provide a layer between the application and the actual database. However with AWS being very confusing, in my opinion, i'm super lost.

Could any of you gentle folks provided with the step-by-step guide what services to use, how to connect them together and deploy them in order to be able to use it in my android application. Or maybe an article describing the steps? I don't really need a detailed explanation just a nudge in the right direction and I will try to figure out the rest.

Thank you greatly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions like "Looking for tutorials/articles on xyz" is considered off-topic. Given that Amazon has many articles, tutorials, and samples on their site. You might get a better response if you have a specific problem (with the understanding that Amazon has lots of solutions for a variety of deployment scales: 5 users a day to 1000s per second).

Comment: What is the purpose of using MySQL database? What sort of entities you have? Also have you considered NoSQL? Just asking these to understand the actual requirements since there are many solutions available in AWS to persist data in a backend.

Comment: @Ashan the reason is that I'm going to use NoSQL database for real-time data such as login, location, push notification etc. However I want to use MySQL for data like payments. And so I want to connect both database through several API's in order to use it efficiently/securely.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I understand its not looking for tutorial, but I just searched any good explanation for about 2 days now and couldn't find anything decent and so I though I would ask in order to possibly have a nudge in a right direction where I can read and understand how to implement my ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, connecting to MySQL directly from an Android application is not secure, since you need the MySQL database access credentials for the app to communicate with the database.

This is why people recommend using a REST API Layer in between the MySQL database which you can implement using API Gateway and Lambda. This can be secured using a strong authentication mechanism for the API and using SSL for encrypting the messages at Transit.

However, this is not the case if you plan to connect to AWS DynamoDB from Android App. You can enforce Fine-Grained Access Permission to DynamoDB tables and roles using IAM policies.

Few Tutorials that might help,

- [Serverless REST API in Minutes with Serverless Framework](https://blog.codeship.com/a-serverless-rest-api-in-minutes/).
- [Querying RDS MySQL with NodeJS Lambda Function](http://querying-rds-mysql-db-with-nodejs-lambda-function).
- [Using Mobile Hub (To Simplify Things)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html).
- [User Authentication with Cognito UserPools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html).